# Error en Chrome con carousel de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-carousel

Saludos estoy tratando de hacer un carousel de bootstrap con múltiples items en angular. Lo curioso es que funciona en Internet Explorer y Firefox pero en Chrome no funciona.

en Firefox e Internet Explorer:
[image: esto es en firefox y explorer]

en Chrome:
[image: pero en chrome sale asi]

No sé en que podría estar fallando. Cuál será el error o tal vez alguna configuración. Gracias por la ayuda

Este es el código del carousel

```
<h1>ANGULAR:</h1>
   <div ng-app='angularRoutingApp'>
   <div  ng-controller="ruta_hbo_max" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="10000" id="hbo_mas">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="data in datos  track by $index">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p>{{data.ruta}}</p>
                  <a><img ng-src="{{ data.ruta }}"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

y este el query para mostrar las imagenes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("entrando d");
        $('.item').each(function(){
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (!next.length)
                {
              alert();
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }
            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

            for (var i=0;i<2;i++) 
            {
                next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) 
            {
              next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Si estás usando angular para que implementas tu código con jquery? Si lo que necesitas es el carrousel de bootstrap y angular usa http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#carousel

Comment: pero asi solo muestra imagenes de uno a uno yo ocupo que muestre de 4

Comment: El atributo `data-type="multi"` no parece formar parte del API del carousel de bootstrap [3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) y [4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/). Tienes algún otro código modificando el carousel?

Comment: no solo que las imagenes vienen de una base de datos que traigo con una API Rest con slimp php y consumo con angular resource